# Identifying Discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

### Definitions

> - If the function $f(x)$ has finite limits and not all three numbers $f(x_0)$, $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^-}{f(x_0)}$, $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^+}{f(x_0)}$, then $x_0$ is called a **discontinuity of the first kind**.
> - In particular, if $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^-}{f(x_0)} = \lim\limits_{x \to x_0^+}{f(x_0)}$, then $x_0$ is called a **removable discontinuity**.
> - Discontinuities of a function that are not of the first kind are called **discontinuities of the seconds kind**.
> - **Infinite discontinuities** also belong to the discontinuities of the second kind. These are points $x_0$ such that at least one of the one-sided limits, $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^-}{f(x_0)}$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^+}{f(x_0)}$, is equal to $\pm \infty$.

---

### Question

> **What are some techniques for identifying discontinuities** without looking at the graph of $f(x)$ and eye-balling $f(x_0)$?

---

### Example

> Identify the discontinuity of $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x - 2}$.

$x - 2 = 0$ when $x = 2$. So, the discontinuity is at $x_0 = 2$.

$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^-}{f(x_0)} = -k$ (where $k \geq 0$) because the numerator always positive and the denominator is a small negative number.

$\lim\limits_{x \to x_0^+}{f(x_0)} = +k$ (where $k \geq 0$) because the numerator always positive and the denominator is a small positive number.

So far, the discontinuity might be **the second kind** or **infinite**.

At this point, I know of no obvious way of honing in on the type of discontinuity quickly. All I can think of is attempting to solve $\lim\limits_{x \to 2}{\frac{x^2}{x - 2}}$.

Comment: If $f(x)=g(x)/h(x)$ for $x\ne 2$ where the limit  $\lim_{x\to 2}g(x)$ exists and is not $0$, and where$ 0=\lim_{x\to 2}h(x)$ then $|g(x)/h(x)|\to \infty$ as $x\to 2.$

Comment: Is this a quote from a text? What is its level? High-school? Undergraduate?

Comment: @Lubin -- Yes (though not perfectly verbatim); Undergraduate

Comment: Well, in my (perhaps outdated!) lexicon, these would be called singularities, not discontinuities. The general definition of continuity requires a precondition that the function must be *defined* at $x_0$. So for the case $f(x)=x^2/(x-2)$, since the function is not defined at $2$, it wouldn’t even be grammatical to say whether $f$ was continuous or discontinuous there. Part of the difficulty is that elementary texts seem categoricallly to refuse to discuss the issue of what the domain of definition of the function in question might be. To see that it’s “infinite”, note that it gets huge near 2